# Adapting plugin for custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox, wpdb

I am trying to reformulate a function (in a plugin) so that it applies to posts in a custom post type rather than normal posts.

```
 function saving_posts($post_id)
{
    global $wpdb, $user_ID;
    $this->setup_links();
    if(defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE)
        return;
    if('post' == $_POST['post_type'])
    {
        if(!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id))
            return;
    }
    else
        return;
    $mydata = ($_POST['mf_post_to_forum'] == 'true')?true:false;
    if($mydata)
    {
        $date = $this->wpf_current_time_fixed('mysql', 0);
        $fid = (int)$_POST['mf_post_to_forum_forum'];
        $_POST['mf_post_to_forum'] = 'false'; //Eternal loop if this isn't set to false
        $post = get_post($post_id);
        $sql_thread = "INSERT INTO {$this->t_threads} (last_post, subject, parent_id, `date`, status, starter) VALUES('{$date}', '".$this->strip_single_quote($post->post_title)."', '{$fid}', '{$date}', 'open', '{$user_ID}')";
        $wpdb->query($sql_thread);
        $tid = $wpdb->insert_id;
        $sql_post = "INSERT INTO {$this->t_posts} (text, parent_id, `date`, author_id, subject) VALUES('".$this->input_filter($wpdb->escape($post->post_content))."', '{$tid}', '{$date}', '{$user_ID}', '".$this->strip_single_quote($post->post_title)."')";
        $wpdb->query($sql_post);
        $new = $post->post_content."\n".'<p><a href="'.$this->get_threadlink($tid).'">'.__("Join the Forum discussion on this post", "mingleforum").'</a></p>';
        $post->post_content = $new;
        wp_update_post($post);
    }
}
```

I assumed I could just change `if('post' == $_POST['post_type'])` to `if('my_custom_post' == $_POST['post_type'])` and the rest would work the same. The `$mydata`value comes from here:

```
function send_wp_posts_to_forum()
{
    add_meta_box('mf_posts_to_forum', __('Mingle Forum Post Options', 'mingleforum'), array(&$this, 'show_meta_box_options'), 'my_custom_post');
}
function show_meta_box_options()
{
    $forums = $this->get_forums();
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="mf_post_to_forum" value="true" />&nbsp;'.__('Add this post to', 'mingleforum');
    echo '&nbsp;<select name="mf_post_to_forum_forum">';
    foreach($forums as $f)
        echo '<option value="'.$f->id.'">'.$f->name.'</option>';
    echo '</select><br/><small>'.__('Do not check this if this post has already been linked to the forum!', 'mingleforum').'</small>';
}
```

which works fine as the meta box is present in the right place.

Comment: What is the problem?  [`get_post()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post) does work for custom post types as far as I know since it works of of ID number. No mention in the codex otherwise.

Comment: "I assumed I could just change `if('post' == $_POST['post_type'])` to `if('custom_post_type' == $_POST['post_type'])` and the rest would work the same." -- That will only work if your custom post type is named `custom_post_type`.  If you've called it `book`, for example, then you'd need `if ( 'book' == $_POST['post_type'] )` instead.

Comment: I just called it `custom_post_type` for the sake of the example. I just cant figure out why it won't won't work with the custom post yet it works fine with the post. It is actually called match_report.

Comment: `get_post` works fine with a CPT. I just tested it. Please try to locate exactly where the failure occurs. Put `var_dump('something'); die;` in the callback and work out which one of those `if` conditionals (I am guessing) is causing the problem.

Comment: I think the problem is with the meta box on the custom post type admin page. The value (checked) isn't saving when I update the post.

Comment: @s_ha_dum I've tested just about everything and I'm pretty sure the problem is with `add_action("publish_post", array(&$this, "saving_posts"));` in the function `setup_links()` So I guess I need to find the appropriate tag for the hook `add_action()`

Comment: I used `"save_post"`and got it working. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with `$this->setup_links();` which used `add_action("publish_post", array(&$this, "saving_posts"));` instead of `add_action("save_post", array(&$this, "saving_posts"));`

Apparently `publish_post` doesn't work with custom post types.